# Package 'rubygems' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, ruby

As the title states, trying to get rubygems on my computer but it won't seem to find the package. Does the message mean that ruby has replaced it, and that I do not need it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rubygems` is a virtual package, check the [Ubuntu package archive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/rubygems1.9.1). A virtual package is not an actual package, it has no `.deb` file associated with it. A group of packages that provide some generic functionalities are represented by using a virtual package so that any given package can depend on the virtual package rather than needing to know whats the actual package providing the functionalities.

In your case the virtual package is `rubygems` and the physical package is `ruby`. As `ruby` provides the functionalities that the virtual package `rubygems` indicates, you are getting the message that `rubygems` is replaced by `ruby`.

Answer (score 1):

So in other words you should get rubygems integegration, try `sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration`